# Apache Mod rewrite: remove everything after ::

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved a shop from xtc:modified to shopware.
The URLs look almost the same:

http://example.com/category/article**::123.html**

http://example.com/category/article

The only difference is ::123.html, 123 being different numbers.

Could you please provide me with the correct rewrite code to get rid of the :: and everything behind it?
I can't find the solution...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I did figure it out after a couple of more hours of trial and error:

> RedirectMatch permanent (.+?)::.+$ https://www.example.com$1